# Who incurs computer time using Puppeteer in a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Let's say I fire up Puppeteer (headless Chrome) in a Cloud Function, and Puppeteer navigates to a public website and that website does something computationally intensive.

The computation is occurring on the "client side," but it's being visited by a cloud function -- so who incurs the compute time?

Comment: "*who incurs the compute time*" Who would you *expect* to incur the "compute time" for any cloud function other than you...? Can you share the logic you followed to get to any ambiguity in this conclusion? What documentation are you looking at that would imply or explicitly state that someone else would be incurring compute time for a function *you* deployed...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pay CPU charges for the Cloud Function as long as it's active, so between the moment it starts and the moment it finishes (or the return value resolves). It doesn't really matter whether it's computing something itself, or waiting for another process to return something.

Comment: Yes, and sorry if I'm not understanding, but if Puppeteer initiates a Long Client-Side Operation and then the Cloud Function ends, will **(A)** Puppeteer wait for the LCSO to end, keeping the CF alive **(B)** the CF but the LCSO continues [running on what?] **(C)** both the CF and the LCSO end?

Comment: If the Cloud Function is terminated by the hosting container, puppeteer is also terminated since (if I understand your use-case correctly) it is running in the same process. Whether the public web site continues to operate is impossible to say without limiting to a specific site, but either way: your Cloud Function won't be charged for this.

Comment: Ah, this: "Whether the public web site continues to operate".  I'm having a hard time imagine where the visited site "lives", if not in the cloud function itself.  So you're saying that when Puppeteer leaves, it's the configuration of the public site that determines whether it continues to run?  If I *am* understanding correctly, I'll make a new question about Puppeteer.  Thanks for working through this.

Comment: Puppeteer is just like a browser here. What happens when you start to load your shopping cart on Amazon, then quickly close the tab? It's impossible for us to say that without seeing how Amazon's server-side code deals with that. **If** you open a new question for that part, I recommend being very specific about the web site that you're calling. In the meantime, I hope I've answered what happens in Cloud Functions here.

Comment: Ha, point taken!